# Shortest Chord from origin to function

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

[image]

worked solution:

[image]

Is this found using the distance of a line equation, where instead of co-ordinate points they use functions, so the two functions are g(x) and x (because the origin is on the line y=x)

Comment: I think it's just the formula for the distance from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$, where $(x,y)$ is constrained to lie on the graph of the function.

Comment: If you evaluated your differentiation correctly and got correct value of x for which the derivative is zero that you are right. There is no need for any line equation at all.

Comment: You can minimise the distance more easily by minimising the square of the distance, which comes to the same thing. Then you won't have to differentiate any square roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point $Q$ on the graph has coordinates $Q=(x_Q,g(x_Q))$. The origin $O$ has coordinates $O=(0,0)$. The distance between two points $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$ is $d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$. In your case you will get that $d$ is a function of $x_Q$. The minimum of this function gives what you are searching for.